How to disable/enable save and print features in Word on Mac platform using an Office add-in?
I am developing a security system for the Mac platform that will enable or disable Word's save and print features based on the user's access permissions.
I have reviewed the Office add-in development documentation, but I cannot find a way to accomplish this. Am I missing something, or is there a workaround?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
